# Exposing a COM interface from a VB.Net Winforms application

Tags: vb.net, com

I was wondering if it's possible to expose a COM interface through a Winforms executable rather than having to create a class library DLL? I have a small interactive application that I'd like users to be able to call from VBScript and other languages using code such as:

Set USBDAQ = CreateObject("USBDAQ.Control")
USBDAQ.TakeSample()

I could create a seperate class library and use a form of IPC to talk to the main application but I'd rather not add the extra complexity. I know there are probably reliability advantages to that method but it doesn't have to be particularly robust.

Comment: You are asking for an out-of-process server, .NET does not have good support for it.  There is no decent way to get the server registered and to publish your class factories.  The usual approach is COM+ hosting but afaik that doesn't permit a UI.  You are better off doing this with WCF or Remoting.

Comment: Thanks Hans that saved me looking further. Because the requirements are so simple I decided to use System.IO.Pipes because named pipes are easy to use from VBS. WCF seems like it would be a good choice which I'll keep in mind in the future for anything that needs to be a bit more robust / complex.

Comment: @Hans Passant - I was pretty new here when I posted the question but your comment answered my question, if you'd like to post as an answer I'll mark as accepted so the question is closed. Otherwise if you'd rather not I'll wait a week or so and post as answered myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Hans Passant with his comment I quickly found that indeed .NET does not have good support for implementing a COM out-of-process server. After research his suggestion of WCF or Remoting seems the most appropriate for most applications.

Because my requirements were so simple I ended up using System.IO.Pipes because named pipes are easy to use from VBS in a single direction and I only needed to send simple requests in a single direction.